# Extract substring from ls

Tags: linux, bash, unix, substring

I'm creating a little script and I have to list all my Tomcat binaries. 
So far I was able to do this:
`ls -1 | grep '\-tomcat\-' | cut -f3 -d'-'`

This basically lists all the versions, but it adds the .zip or .tar.gz

```
5.5.17.zip
5.5.26.tar.gz
5.5.27.tar.gz
5.5.28.tar.gz
5.5.31.tar.gz
5.5.32.tar.gz
```

I would like to know how to remove the .zip and .tar.gz from the extracted strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or simplify the whole approach:

```
ls apache-tomcat*|sed -r 's/^.*-([0-9.]+)\..*/\1/'
```

Less tools, and it gives you the version numbers.

P.S.: Following up on @Nemo's suggestion: we let shell globbing and prior knowledge take care of half the job (just list things that actually look like apache-tomcat).  When piping ls' output to another tool the -1 is moot, so we get rid of that.  sed takes the values coming from ls, matches beginning of line to the first - followed by a digit, the parenthesis remember all digits & literal periods, and then we match the rest of the string till end of line (implicit).  And then the whole match gets replaced with the remembered digits & periods.

Comment: +1, that's what I wanted to post. However, some explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 5):

Pipe it through another `cut`:

```
ls -1 | grep '-tomcat-' | cut -f3 -d'-' | cut -f1-3 -d'.'
```

This will work as long as the versions all have three components.  If the version is just 5.5, it won't work.

Another option would be just to use `sed`:

```
ls -1 | grep '-tomcat-' | cut -f3 -d'-' | sed 's/.tar.gz\|.zip//'
```

This will remove `.tar.gz` or `.zip` from the strings.

Answer (score 1):

`ls -1 | awk -F. '/-tomcat-/ {print $1}'`

a solution using awk. All previous answers would work just the same.

EDIT:

I may have misunderstood, perhaps this is what youre after:

`ls -1 | awk -F\- '/tomcat/ {print substr($3,0,6)}'`